# $L$ is the algebraic closure of $K$ if and only if $L$ is the splitting field for all elements of $K[x]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

In an exercise given in class, we're tasked with proving that **the field $L$ is an algebraic closure for the field $K$ if and only if $L=K(R)$** (the smallest field containing $K \cup R$), where $R$ is the set of all roots of all polynomials $f \in K[x]$ (i.e. the splitting field for the whole of $K[x]$). **The forward direction I believe I can solve**. Clearly every polynomial splits in an algebraically closed field, and since every element of $L$ is algebraic over $K$, we have $L \subseteq K(R)$ and $K(R) \subseteq L$ is clear. **For the converse, I think I can prove that $L/K$ is algebraic.** Every element $ \alpha \in K(R)$ (or its inverse) can be written as a polynomial in a finite number of elements $\{\beta_1, \dots, \beta_n\} \subseteq R$. So $\alpha$ is contained in the field $K(\beta_1, \dots, \beta_n)$, which is algebraic over $K$ and hence $\alpha$ is algebraic over $K$. **I don't know where to start with proving that $K(R)$ is algebraically closed however**. Any help would be appreciated.

My defition of an algebraic closure is an algebraically closed field $L$ such that the extension $L/K$ is algebraic.

Possible solution:

Let $f(x)=\alpha_0+\alpha_1x+\dots+\alpha_nx^n \in K(R)[x]$, $n \geq 2$. Suppose $f$ has no root in $K(R)$. Let $p$ be an irreducible factor of $f$ of degree $\geq 2$. Then $p$ has a root in the field $K(R)[x]/(p)$ given by $\beta := \bar{x}$. However, $K(R)[x]/(p)$ is an algebraic over $K(R)$ and hence algebraic over $K$ so that $\beta$ is algebraic over $K$ and hence $\beta \in K(R)$, contradicting the fact that $p$ has no roots in $K(R)$ since it's irreducible and of degree $\geq 2$.

Comment: Any element that is algebraic over an algebraic extension of $K$ is algebraic over $K$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks for your response. I edited the post with a possible solution. I'm not sure if its the direction your hint was supposed to lead me.

Comment: There is no need to argue by contradiction: to show $K(R)$ is algebraically closed, let $\alpha$ be algebraic over $K(R)$. Then it is algebraic over $K$, hence a root of a polynomial in $K[x]$, hence in $R$, hence in $K(R)$.